# How to create schema by using Schema.from_lists method in Alibaba ODPS python SDK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, alibaba-cloud

I usually create the schema by initializing through table columns and optional partitions. I understand creating schema via `Schema.from_lists` method in Alibaba ODPS python SDK is far better in terms of LOC and performance.

The code I often use to create the schema is:

```
from odps.models import Schema, Column, Partition
columns = [Column(name='num', type='bigint', comment='the column')]
partitions = [Partition(name='pt', type='string', comment='the partition')]
schema = Schema(columns=columns, partitions=partitions)
print(schema.columns)
```

Output:

```
[<column num, type bigint>, <partition pt, type string>]
```

How to create the schema by using `Schema.from_lists` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create by passing four lists.

```
In [33]: Schema.from_lists(['num'], ['bigint'], ['pt'], ['string'])             
Out[33]: 
odps.Schema {
  num   bigint      
}
Partitions {
  pt    string      
}
```

The downside is that by this way, you cannot specify the comment of columns any more.